# Bits of webpage showing before Fakeloader

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using fakeloader to preload my content [here](http://www.gamingreport.com), however I noticed that my site header tends to show before the fakeloader preload animation. Is there anyway I can hold off showing the content until the preload is done with fakeloader?

This is the javascript I am using to initialise Fakeloader

```
$("#fakeLoader").fakeLoader({
    timeToHide:1200,
    zIndex:"999",
    spinner:"spinner5",
    bgColor:"#fa520a"
});
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a backdrop for your fake loader by placing a fixed div top/left 0, width/height 100% in your body, and remove it after your loader is done initiating.

```
<div class="flbackdrop"></div>
```

and CSS

```
.flbackdrop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 99999; /*Making sure its on top*/
}
```

And after your fakeloader has been initialized:

```
$(".flbackdrop").remove();
```

This does not only hide your navbar, but it hides **everything** that might come up before your loader.

Comment: This worked. Had to add "position:absolute" to the flbackdrop css to get it to display properly though.

Comment: Sorry, i did indeed dorget that. Beter make it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Hide your `navbar` using `$('.navbar').hide();` and after the call to `fakeLoader`, show the navbar using `$('.navbar').show();`

Answer (score 0):

Add this script tag just after your opening head tag. It will hide the nav bar for first 1200 seconds. This is a hacky solution since `fakeLoader` doesn't have any mechanism for passing callback.

```
<script>  
    document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].style.display = "none";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].style.display = "block";
    }, 1201);
</script>
```